# Mule ESB groovy evaluator key cannot be empty exception

Tags: groovy, mule

I am having problems with a groovy evaluator in mule that gets an invocation property from the message and chekcs if it is null. The code is:

```
<when expression="#[groovy: (message.getInvocationProperty('firstName', null) != null)]">
```

This throws"

```
 1.key can not be empty (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  javax.script.SimpleBindings:-1 (null)
 2. key can not be empty (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type:         String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
```

org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

At this point i know that firstName property is indeed null - it is not set in the message, but shouldn`t getInvocationProperty('firstName', null) set the property to null as a default value if it is not set?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which Mule ESB version are you using? Have you tried to use [MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL)?

Comment: I am using 3.5, and yes i have tried using MEL, but when using MEL i get a SAX parse exception saying that "when" tag must be followed by attribute > or />. Should there a be a special evaluator attribute when using MEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem by upgrading mule and using MEL. So the expression now looks like this.

```
<when expression="#[flowVars.firstName != empty]">
```

'flowVars' stores all invocation properties and variables assigned in the flow, and if the flow has been called through the

```
<flow-ref />
```

all the variables set in the caller flow will be available through the 'flowVars'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this choice:

```
<flow name="loan-broker">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="8080" path="in" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <set-variable variableName="prop" value="value" />
    <choice>
        <when expression="#[flowVars['prop'] != null]" >
            <set-payload value="#['prop: ' + flowVars['prop']]"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-payload value="Houston, we have a problem."/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Call it using:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/in
```

You should get *value*

Comment: Hi Ale, and thanks for the response. I have tried that but the scope of the properties i am setting is invocation, i am not sure, but i think that properties added to the message in invocation scope cannot be accessed using inboundProperties[]. I have tried using  flowVars and MEL but that generates SAX parsing exception saying that "when must be followed by attribute, > or />".

Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more complete flow, please try with it.

Comment: I have tried the example that you have sent me, but mule does not deploy the application because on startup i get this exception:

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "when" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Any ideas why this is happening? This is the line that is breaking in my code:

`<when expression="#[flowVars['message'] != null]"‌​>`

Comment: Is it possible that your config has a different encoding? It happened to me that I've copied code from MuleSoft doc site and had a different enconding, everything seemed right but got some strange errors like you are having. Try deleting and rewriting that line from scratch.

Comment: Rewriting it helped! But now i get a different exception.

Exception stack is:
`1. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:json.message" returned null but a value was required.
2. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:json.message" returned null but a value was required.`

I know that message is null, but there is a use case in which this flow is called when it might not be null so i need to check if it is null with the mentioned when command.

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Are you sure that this error is in the same expression as before?

Comment: Nop, sorry for not making it clearer. This exception comes from set-variable statement. I have a custom processor that parses a JSON and based on the fields in that JSON it sets a number of message properties in the INVOCATION scope of the message. I am trying to get the 'message' invocation property from the mule message, see if it is null in the when statement and based on the result do something. If JSON received does not contain the 'message' field, the 'message' property of the mule message will not be set.

Comment: I'm not sure about what is going on, add some code, please

Comment: `<custom-processor class="example.package.JsonProcessor">
    <spring:property name="valuesToParse">
  <spring:map>
         ..number of properties..
         <spring:entry key="json.messageText" value="//messageBody" />

         ..some more properties.. 
         <spring:map>
     </spring:property>
</custom-processor>

<set-variable variableName="messageText" value="#[variable:json.messageText]" />

<choice>
 <when expression="#[flowVars['messageText'] != null ]">
    .......more code
`

Custom processor parses the incoming json and if the field specified in the spring:map exists...

Comment: ...in the JSON it is added to the invocation scope of the mule message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56978/discussion-between-loshmeey-and-ale-sequeira).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, solved with following expression:

```
<set-variable variableName="firstName" value="${fname}" doc:name="Variable"/>
<when expression="#[flowVars.firstName.isEmpty()]">
     <logger message="===== If ===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>    
</when>
<otherwise>
     <logger message="===== Else ===" level=" INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
</otherwise>
```